# comma operators in c++

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
   int x = 6;
   x = x+2, ++x, x-4, ++x, x+5;
   std::cout << x;
}

// Output: 10
```

---

```
int main() {
   int x = 6;
   x = (x+2, ++x, x-4, ++x, x+5);
   std::cout << x;
}

// Output: 13
```

---

Please explain.

Comment: Please tell me why are you making the code so difficult to read and understand. I do not hope (actually I do hope) that in a few years time you have to maintain it! C++ along with other languages give you enough rope to hang yourself.

Comment: @Ed: Given that it also _does nothing_, it seems obvious that this is a question about the behaviour of the operators, rather than actual code that serves a further purpose.

Comment: @Ed: Some people (myself included) would prefer to know why these things work the way they do, regardless of how readable the code is. Just because the question was asked, doesn't mean that he intends to use this in real-world code.

Comment: @Ed Heal - Since the question writer is asking for the meaning of the comma operator I think it's relatively clear that they are not the author of the code.  Surely it's possible to comment that the use of commas, as in the example, is difficult to read and understand, without personally abusing the question writer.

Comment: This question only has seven upvotes because I made it so pretty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `,` has [lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `=`. In fact, `,` has the lowest precedence of all operators.

***First case:***

```
x=x+2,++x,x-4,++x,x+5;
```

This is equivalent to

```
(x=x+2),(++x),(x-4),(++x),(x+5);
```

So, `x` becomes 6+2 = 8, then it is incremented and becomes 9. The next expression is a no-op, that is `x-4` value is calculated and discarded, then increment again, now `x` is 10, and finally, another no-op. **x is 10**.

***Second case:***

```
x=(x+2,++x,x-4,++x,x+5);
```

This is equivalent to

```
x=((x+2),(++x),(x-4),(++x),(x+5));
```

`x+2` is calculated, then `x` is incremented and becomes 7, then `x - 4` is calculated, then `x` is incremented again and becomes 8, and finally `x+5` is calculated which is 13. This operand, being the rightmost one, is the taken as the result of the whole comma expression. This value is assigned to `x`. 
**x is 13.**

Hope it's clear.

And, as one of the comments suggests -

## NEVER WRITE CODE LIKE THIS

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal No, because the comma operator introduces a sequence point. I would still *never* write code like this.

Comment: or in more technical language, "lower precedence". it is particularly infuriating for Norwegian programmers, who may write e.g. `x = 3,14;`. Heh.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't believe so, since the comma operator is a sequence point, each of the operations must be performed in a well-defined order.

Comment: @MarkB: OK. :) I'm never entirely sure.

Comment: @armen tsirunyan:what is  no-op?please explain?

Comment: @gautam: That means it has no side-effects. The value is calculated but isn't assigned to anything, so it's the same as if it wasn't calculted at all

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Precedence plays a role here, but it's not why there's no undefined behavior. It's all due to the fact that the `,` operator is a sequence point.

Comment: @armen tsiruyan:when does no-op occur?

Comment: @omnifarious: while what you write is literally true, it is bafflingly irrelevant to anything other than conveying a false, negative impression of what i've written. so i ask you straight: wtf do you mean?

Comment: @gautam: Consider this: `int x = 5; x+2;`  x+2 is a no-op. It doesn't **do** anything. `x+=2`, on the other hand, is not a no-op, because it changes x's value.

Comment: @Alf: Omnifarious mistakenly believed that your first comment was in response to the discussion on UB that I started, rather than to the answer.

Comment: @Tomalak: ah, thanks! omnifarious: then just ignore my response. sorry.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan -- I don't believe it's correct to call `x+2` a noop, compiler still has to evaluate the expression, though it's at its discretion to optimize it away.

Comment: @Gene: In this context I mean *effectively* no-op.